# Rails 3 Sunspot Limiting Selected Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, limit, sunspot

at the moment I'm doing a Select from multiple tables using Sunspot. I'm limiting the records selected with the condition that the creation date must have been within the past 5 days. However I would like to take this further and limit the number of records selected to say, 20? Is there any way to do this with sunspot? I'm not doing any fancy groupings or anything. Simply selecting records belonging to various models and displaying them onto the screen.

My current code:

```
@updates = Sunspot.search(Upload,Help, User...) do
      with(:created_at).greater_than(5.days.ago)      
      order_by(:created_at, :desc)
end
```

I tried adding the 'limit' clause as specified by the [readme](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) on Github but that produced an undefined method error probably because I'm doing a global Sunspot search as opposed to a search on a specific model.

Error code:

```
@updates = Sunspot.search(Upload,Help, User...) do
          with(:created_at).greater_than(5.days.ago)      
          order_by(:created_at, :desc)
          limit(20)
end
```

Error message:

```
undefined method `limit' for #<Sunspot::DSL::Search:0x0000000790b8c8>
```

Comment: Post the code the generates the error and the snippet of the error itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "limit" method is for "groups". See [the readme section on groups](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#grouping). Sunspot provides pagination (and works like a charm with [the kaminari gem](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) btw). [See the section on solr pagination](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#pagination) in the readme. Specifically, try this:

```
@updates = Sunspot.search(Upload,Help, User...) do
  with(:created_at).greater_than(5.days.ago)      
  order_by(:created_at, :desc)
  paginate page: 1, per_page: 20
end
```

Comment: Now if I had say 10,000 records would the query search for all 10,000 and then skim it down to 20 or would it simply select the 20 that it needs?

Comment: the pagination is done by solr and it is done very efficiently. so, in the above sunspot query, solr returns the first 20 documents ordered by the create date. If you want 21 - 40, set page: 2. With the Kaminari gem, you would set page: params[:page].

Comment: Ok this sounds great then because the query I'm running occurs on the homepage and that's the last place I want any performance hits. Thank you for your input.

Comment: That was the plan, just as soon as I get the chance to try the code